# sending data from c++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have a c++ application that streams out data. I need to add a function in my C# application that listens for, and stores this data. I have some c++ knowledge, and some C# knowledge, but no networking experience. I am unable to use dll marshaling in this case.

What is a fairly simple, low latency way to send and receive this data? Should I be using Sockets/ports? or named pipes?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes.  Or yes.  You can get more yeses.

Comment: Low-latency? try UDP + headaches.

Answer (score -1):

Your query is pretty vague, but what I would do is create a library in one language and import it in another language. For example, you could create a new Project in visual studio called "Class Library". And then add the following code.

```
public static class Fncs
{
    public static void Temp()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("UgityBugityBoo");
    }
}
```

And then press F5 to build the library. Then create a C++ project and add the DLL file created by the previous project to "references". Then you can use subroutines and classes from this library like so.

```
#include <previousCsharplibrary>

int main()
{
    Fncs.Temp();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Love it when people downvote without commenting ^_^